# Querying across many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create arrays of two types of users: priority and member. Priorty users have created events, while members are those that have not created events. The function below is supposed to sort Users into priority or member, allocate priority users first, and if there's room in the event (as indicated by guests), it'll randomly add member users. I'm getting the following error message at the end:

```
undefined method `id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00000001c27828>
```

How do I get the User class, as opposed to the ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation class?

### event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :event_users
    has_many :users, :through => :event_users
    belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

### eventuser.rb

```
class EventUser < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :event
end
```

### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :events, :through => :event_users
  has_many :created_events, :class_name => "Event"

  def do_randomize
    priority = self.users.where('events_created > ?', 0)
    regular = self.users.where('events_created = ?', 0)
    winners = []
    priority_winners = priority.limit(guests).order('users.events_created    DESC')
    remaining_slots = self.guests - priority_winners.count

    if remaining_slots <= 0
        winners << priority_winners
    else
        regular_winners = regular.limit(remaining_slots).order("RANDOM()")
        winners << priority_winners << regular_winners
    end
    winners.each do |winner|
        puts winner.id
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a lot closer than you think. This line is your issue:

```
winners << priority_winners
```

The [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) (usually called "append") operator on an array actually adds the right-hand argument as a *new, single element* to your array. Meaning, `[] << 1` returns `[1]`. But what you're doing is more like `[] << [1]`, which adds the right-hand array as a new element to your original array and returns `[[1]]`. Hence, iterating over it returns your association instead of each winner.

To fix this, simply use the array [concatenation operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) instead, `+`:

```
winners += priority_winners
```

And do the same for your other uses of `<<`, too:

```
winners += priority_winners + regular_winners
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Life saver. Any tips on how to streamline the code? Doesn't feel very ruby-esque.

Comment: 1. Use scopes for your `priority` and `regular` user definitions; e.g., `scope :priority, -> { where('events_created > ?', 0) }`. Then you can refer to `users.priority` to get a list of priority users. 2. ` winners << priority_winners` is the same in both branches of your `if` statement; just do that first and then append onto it if `remaining_slots > 0`.